# Resend Validation Email in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm making a website for a client and using Cognito Forms.

I used my email address originally so I could test if the forms were being received. Everything was good and I was getting notifications fines.

Now I've changed it to my client's email but he doesn't appear to be getting any notifications in his inbox when I fill in and send forms to him.

I see that I may have to validate the email but I see no way to resend the validation code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

If you have changed the email address in the from's "Submission Settings" then you will not need to revalidate the email address. You will only need to revalidate if you change the email address for the account.

Email notification might be getting held or blocked at your clients email provider or placed in a spam/junk folder. I would be happy to help trouble shoot and check to verify that the email's are going out and are being delivered if you would like to submit a [Bug Report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/), so that you don't have to publicly share your email address or your clients email address.